# Почему в 1С возникает проблема с организациями?

Tags: 1с

Есть несколько профилей у пользователя. Часть с ограничением по организациям, часть нет. Но пользователь почему-то всё равно видит все организации в разных таблицах.

Попробовал вычислить профиль из-за которого были проблемы. Убрал у пользователя все профили и начал их добавлять по одному, чтобы понять на каком всё сломается и пользователь снова начнет видеть все организации. Таким образом вернул все профили, кроме последнего. На нем как раз всё сломалось. Но когда я убрал его еще раз, чтобы удостовериться, что в нем была причина, то проблема осталась. То есть до последнего профиля пользователь видел только необходимые организации, после добавления все, а после удаления по-прежнему все.

С чем это может быть связано?

Если убрать все профили и заново их добавлять, то всё работает как надо (до добавления последнего профиля)

Comment: Может, вы просто крайний раз убирая роль, забыли запустить сеанс заново?!

Comment: Согласен с предыдущим комментом ! После добавления/удаления профиля - желательно выйти из 1с (этому юзеру) и зайти снова; И только после этого проверить.